# Enterprise Library - configuring exception handling

Tags: c#, frameworks, enterprise

I'm having some problems configuring the exception handler the way I want it. What I want is to log the warnings and above in one file (errors.txt) and everything (including the warnings and errors) in a file named all.txt.

The problem is that I can't get the errors to be logged in all.txt, I only get an entry in errors.txt and a separate file named {guid}all.txt with the error inside.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and help me on the right track?

```
<exceptionHandling>  <exceptionPolicies>
<add name="Default">
  <exceptionTypes>
    <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        postHandlingAction="None">
      <exceptionHandlers>
        <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            logCategory="Errors" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
            formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
            priority="0" />
      </exceptionHandlers>
    </add>
  </exceptionTypes>
</add>  </exceptionPolicies></exceptionHandling>

<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="false" defaultCategory="All" evertImpersonation="false">  <listeners>
<add name="All Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    fileName="Logs\All.txt" footer="" formatter="All Formatter"
    header="" rollInterval="Day" maxArchivedFiles="7" />
<add name="Errors Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    fileName="Logs\Errors.txt" formatter="Errors formatter" rollInterval="Day"
    maxArchivedFiles="7" filter="Warning" />  </listeners>  <formatters>
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    template="{timestamp(local:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff)} - {severity} - {message}"
    name="All Formatter" />
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff)}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
    name="Errors formatter" />  </formatters>  <logFilters>
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    enabled="true" name="Logging Enabled Filter" />  </logFilters>  <categorySources>
<add switchValue="All" name="All">
  <listeners>
    <add name="All Listener" />
  </listeners>
</add>
<add switchValue="Warning" name="Errors">
  <listeners>
    <add name="Errors Listener" />
    <add name="All Listener" />
  </listeners>
</add>  </categorySources>  <specialSources>
<allEvents switchValue="Off" name="All Events" />
<notProcessed switchValue="Off" name="Unprocessed Category" />
<errors switchValue="Off" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />  </specialSources></loggingConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Enterprise Library. I'd recommend using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which provides a much richer error handling experience and is substantially easier to configure...

Comment: +1 vote for saying don't use Enterpise Library, I haven't used ELMAH though so I can't comment about that.

Comment: @Jason : Please specify that why you forbid Enterprise Library ?? I've already implemented it in my solution and it works pretty nice..

Comment: Disclaimer: It has been a long time since I've used it and since I posted my original comment so this may not be valid any more.  My main reason for disliking enterprise library is due to the complexity of setting it up properly.  It just seems like a lot of extra config for not a lot of gain.  You can already do a lot with the built in tracing and if you need to can generally build a few nice abstractions specifically tailored to your project instead of however the EntLib people thought you should use it.  Some of EntLib's loggers may be useful though.

Comment: It's important to remember that ELMAH is for ASP.NET only.